# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

that is the code i connect to untrusted server but i always get this error i put the code in the using statement but it is not working return empty string 
also tried and see the link of this issue before but it is not working

```
private String requestAndResponse(String url)
    {
        string responseValue = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        // for un trusted servers
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        try
        {
            using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("error code " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }

            //process the response stream ..(json , html , etc..  )
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            StreamReader loResponseStream = new
                StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);

            responseValue = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            loResponseStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }



        return responseValue;
    }
```

Comment: `response` only exists inside the `using` scope...you're trying to acess it outside. Put your code inside the `using` scope.

Comment: @ElmerDantas actually no, `response` is declared before the statement.

Comment: You're calling `GetResponseStream` *outside the using statement*. That's definitely broken, and you shouldn't expect that to work. I suggest you edit this question to show the code with it *inside* the `using` statement, with a clearer description of exactly what's going on, and what steps you've taken to diagnose it. (Do you know that the server *is* returning data?) It's not clear what this has to do with the visual-studio or .net-framework-version tags, either.

Comment: @Abbas indeed but he is calling `GetResponseStream` that will only exists inside the `using`

Comment: @ElmerDantas The object (already) exists, it's only disposed of already. Those are two different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `using` block is disposing your response. Move your code after this block into the `using` statement.

Answer (score 5):

On this line:

```
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);
```

You are trying to access `response`, but this object has already been disposed of by the `using` statement before.

**Edit:**

This code should work, disposing of all objects and returning the value:

```
using (HttpWebResponse  response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("error code " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }

    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

    using(StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc))
    {
        return loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Returning from a using statement is allowed, more reading: [**using Statement (C# Reference)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Quote from the site:

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part:

```
using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("error code " +      response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
 }

//process the response stream ..(json , html , etc..  )
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader loResponseStream = new
StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);
```

You are accesing `response` when constructing your `StreamReader`, but this is outside of your `using` statement. The `using` statement will dispose of response, hence the error.